# How to create an Outlook plugin that shows new folders from a non-exchange hosts

Tags: office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

We're looking to create an Outlook COM or Web addin that will display additional folders in the inbox/folders section of outlook.  The data will come from a Rest Webservice.

We know its possible since we've seen in a legal application plugin for outlook COM.

The folders inside the red box are from a third party system that contains references to emails within exchange.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: With a web-addin you could use REST or EWS to create additional Exchange Folders and populate them with items, but it sounds like you want to be able to have those folders automatically show up there and reference data that is coming from non-exchange sources? Which sounds like something more appropriate to COM.

Comment: We have a prototype that used COM and EWS.  Our design requires messages to remain in the inbox while it's also filed in one or more new folders.  The only way we found to do this was to add a Category to the message.  As we wanted to do this for 1000's of messages it became very slow.  It also altered the appearance of the message in inbox.  Pilot customers did not like that.  Any idea how the system in the above screenshot works?  Any sample programs would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Are there any resources within Microsoft we can contact for help??  We contacted DAVID E. CRAIG of the https://theofficecontext.com/ blog and are looking forward to his response.

Comment: It's not possible for the exact same mail message to exist in two folders at the same time. It could be possible that the filing folders are Search Folders? Or something similar? I am not aware with how that third party system implemented their feature, maybe you could contact them? Regardless, doing something similar is probably more of a COM addin project, as a Web Add-in will only give you access to create folders and stuff via REST/EWS, and won't allow you to modify the UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a store provider in C++ (this is as Extended MAPI as it gets and is certainly not for the faint-hearted or those who had no previous MAPI experience).

Or you can add a PST store to Outlook and sync it with your remote web service.